# .deb installer (linux) dependencies. What if it's not in the repository?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, deb, debian-based

I would like my application to install Google Chrome along itself. I simply added a dependency named `google-chrome-stable` to the deb installer and it works.

However, it only works if the target machine has Chrome in its repository (which is not the case on a clean Ubuntu install for instance).

Is there a way to solve that? Can I somehow specify a URL or some other data that enables Linux to resolve the dependency?

Comment: What about using a dependency on the `chromium-browser` which is in the repository?

Comment: awesome, that solves my problem. However, the general issue persists. I can not reference 3rd party software that is not in the predefined sw repository? Is there no way around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem with with `google-chrome` you can add a dependencie with `chromium-browser` which is in the repository.

I don't think it's possibile to automatically add another repository to met the dependencies of your package. You could add the requested dependencie in your package (if it fits) or fail the installation explaning to the user what repository to add and how to add it.
A good `How to install it` guide on your package web-site for example.

Comment: Sounds like a major FAIL on the Debian installer side. Broken at the conceptual level already.

Comment: I don't see it as a  fail. The software in the main repositories of Debian respects the Debian standards on quality and security. Adding another another unofficial repository could add insecure or untested software to the system, so is must a be an user choice.

Comment: Installing a 3rd party software IS a user choice and implies the user's trust to that software vendor. Making it cumbersome for 3rd party software to reference other 3rd party software does not add security. It only prevents users from installing it because it does not "simply work" as the installation of official software does. Whatever the "logic" behind this decision was, we're not gonna change it and have to live with it. Thanks for the pointer to chromium browser!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this script, it will automcatically add the apt repo and installs the chrome https://github.com/jeevandongre/ruby_rails_web

Comment: sure I could write any script / program to solve this. I could simply write my own installer software. The whole point of a installer framework / software center is to avoid this necessity. And the Debian guys actually went quite a far way and did a good job. Just screwed it up on the last mile unfortunately. Guess we have to hope for the next version..